# ¿Cómo acceder al .xml apropiado en Android Translations editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, traducción

Tengo un xml con numerosos textos dentro de `strings-arrays`, tengo entendido que puedes traducir mediante el editor cualquier `string`, mi duda surge por si puedo de alguna manera escoger que xml carga la app.

Ejemplo:

Tenemos 2 xml: `stringsSpanish.xml` y `stringsEnglish.xml`
Dependiendo del idioma del dispositivo que se acceda a uno u a otro sería muy útil, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para traducir textos dispones de una 'tabla' por así decirlo con los diferentes strings y sus traducciones que puedes ir rellenando y añadiendo idiomas. Según el idioma que asignes a la aplicación ésta tomará la traducción adecuada de las que tengas introducidas en tu xml, siempre y  cuando llames a los strings de manera no hardcodeada, `(getString(R.string.mystring))`

El siguiente link puede ayudarte

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo click derecho sobre `strings.xml` y seleccionar `Open Translations Editor`.
Allí aparecen los strings y en las columnas los idiomas, y allí haces las ediciones.

Pero para que aparezcan los idiomas debes de crear los directorios de los idiomas de esta forma:

1. En el panel de la izquierda cambia a `Project`,  click derecho sobre
   `res`, click en `New-Android resource directory`.
2. En `Directory name` por default aparece `values`, solo agrega el codigo de idioma, ej: values-fr, en este caso para el frances.
3. Una vez creado ese directorio, click derecho en el click en `New-Values resource file`, aparece un cuadro que dice `Enter a new file name` y colocas `strings.xml` o `array.xml`, dependiendo. Y así para cada idioma crearas el string.xml